# How to get MCP23s08(8 bit I/O expander) working with GPIO on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio

I have an MCSP23s08( 8-bit SPI  I/O expander) and a Raspberrypi.
Does anyone know what I need to plug where to get them to communicate?I want to read data from MCP23s08 and write it to GPIO  pins of Raspberry Pi?
Is there an SPI python library I can use?

Any example for this?

Answer (score 1):

Lady Ada over at [adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/mcp230xx-gpio-expander-on-the-raspberry-pi/overview) (http://learn.adafruit.com/mcp230xx-gpio-expander-on-the-raspberry-pi/overview) has a very complete write up with code and wiring diagrams.