# Is there an addressable LED product that I can wire to a Raspberry Pi where all the LEDs are separate?

Tags: led

I have a RPi project where I want to build but alas I'm a programmer, not an electrical engineer. I can solder things, but I couldn't tell you what resistor I needed to put where.

Anyway, I looked around and there's lots of led strips, but I need 25-30 separated leds that are individually addressable for my project.

I looked a lot but found nothing, I figured if anybody would know, it would be you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy a couple of MCP23017 port expanders and connect them to the Pi's I2C bus (GPIO 2/3, pins 3/5).

Each MCP23017 has 16 GPIO so that gives you 32 outputs to which you can connect LEDs.  You can connect up to 8 MCP23017 to the I2C bus.

Comment: I'll give this a go. Still not sure how to wire it without burning something out but I found a tutorial that seems to do what I'm trying to do...  http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/how-to-use-a-mcp23017-i2c-port-expander-with-the-raspberry-pi-part-1/#prettyPhoto

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @joan's answer see: [Powering and controlling hundreds of LEDs with a Raspberry pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37990/powering-and-controlling-hundreds-of-leds-with-a-raspberry-pi/37991#37991)

Especially if an off-the-shelf solution is wanted, this might be worth a look: individually addressable LED strips, e.g. based on the LPD8806 ([example](http://www.adafruit.com/product/306)) that seems to have a Pi library.

Answer (score 3):

NeoPixels worked well for me: [NeoPixels on Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/overview)

Very programmer friendly. I got everything up and running with no soldering, and the python library is very easy to use.

- https://youtu.be/71avlEk-QMY
- https://youtu.be/K2sVouSRRnA

Separated leds, like these?

- http://www.adafruit.com/products/1938
- http://www.adafruit.com/products/1734

Comment: hmmm... neat stuff, though you pay what you get for. ~$1.00 an led seems kinda steep, though I don't need many of them. I ordered all the other stuff (the mcp23017) so if I can't muster the brains to make that work, I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: you can find people selling WS2811/2812 LEDs on alibaba.  for me the attraction was a ease of the API.